# Share my google drive data using a website in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-drive-api

I have some files and folders in my Google Drive.And I have a website.
I want to show my Google drive content in one page of my website.Any body can view the those data.

I tried this since morning.Using `javascript` I did that.But in that case it only show the data when I login using that Google account.But from other machine or with out sign in using my account it's not show any data.I checked from `firebug` it's giving a error like login required.

Can any one help me to solve the problem.I will like to do that using `asp.net`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Share a folder with public Internet, use an API key to query the files under that folder with an API key.

```
gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY_HERE);
gapi.client.drive.files.get({
    'q': '"<publicFoldersId>" in parents'
}).execute(callback);
```

Obtain an API key from API Console by generating a key for browsers [1].

Note: I'm using the JavaScript client library, available on [2].

[1] https://developers.google.com/console/help/#generatingdevkeys

[2] https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/

Comment: Hello Thanks for your response.I want to do this using asp.net.Is it possible to share my google drive data to website for all user (user don't need to login)...Please help.I am struggling for last 1 week.. :(